# Can Facebook 'likes' be combined?

Tags: facebook

We have a website with a number of articles which have the *Like* widget added to the page.

In addition to this we also post links to some of these articles on our Facebook fan page wall, which (the post to the wall its self) is also *like*-able.

What we have noticed is that we get some people *liking* the article on our website, and some *liking* the wall post, but we'd prefer to have the total number combined, but I am not sure if this is at all possible, because really they are two different subjects.

Does anyone know if this is something which can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this. Each of these items represent a completely separate open graph item. At this time facebook has no way of merging open graph items.