# Combining Facebook likes of URL and Facebook page

Tags: facebook

Can I combine the Facebook Likes for the URL of my website with the Likes for the Facebook Page of my website?

Specifically: 38k people have "Liked" the fan page for Academic Earth and appear at http://www.facebook.com/academic...

However, an additional 16k people have "Liked" the URL of our homepage (http://academicearth.org/) but they don't show up on our Fan Page.

Is there any way for me to let Facebook know that this URL corresponds to our Facebook page so that those 16k appear on our Facebook Page?Edit

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Facebook 'likes' be combined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878357/can-facebook-likes-be-combined)

Comment: It's awesome that we seem to be the only people on the entire planet that find this strange. I mean, which sense make URL likes if they have no effect on the FB project page ?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is possible, since your website and the Facebook page are treated like two different *objects*.

What I would suggest is promoting your Facebook Page in your website, you can retrieve the number of likes by querying this URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/academicearth
```

Result:

```
{
   "id": "11544573198",
   "name": "Academic Earth",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/hs464.snc4/50284_11544573198_2934981_s.jpg",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/academicearth",
   "category": "Website",
   "website": "http://academicearth.org\n",
   "username": "academicearth",
   "mission": "Academic Earth is an organization founded with the goal of giving everyone on earth access to a world-class education.\n\nAs more and more high quality educational content becomes available online for free, we ask ourselves, what are the real barriers to achieving a world class education?  At Academic Earth, we are working to identify these barriers and find innovative ways to use technology to increase the ease of learning.\n\nWe are building a user-friendly educational ecosystem that will give internet users around the world the ability to easily find, interact with, and learn from full video courses and lectures from the world\u2019s leading scholars.  Our goal is to bring the best content together in one place and create an environment that in which that content is remarkably easy to use and in which user contributions make existing content increasingly valuable.\n\nWe invite those who share our passion to explore our website, participate in our online community, and help us continue to find new ways to make learning easier for everyone.",
   "likes": 39662
}
```

So you can have the link for FB Page and next to it, ***Join the 39662 fan on our Facebook page!***